# Simple techniques to pool and save multiple imputed data in Stata

Tags: stata

I generated 5 series of data of each variable (`child035` `educ035`) with multiple imputation method in Stata. The generated data formatted in the following series.

1. I want to know the best set of the data for my further analysis. I could not get clear message from literature to pool the imputed data for generating a clean set. I believed the series #5 can be the best solution based on the procedural description in the Stata manual.
2. I read the Stata manuals (`mi extract`) and many blog posts on how to save the best set of data in Stata for exporting to Excel but none of the methods worked. I tried in `wide` and `mlong` format, used two different approaches [`mi extract 5` and  `keep if m==5` followed by `replace m=0`] but could not get the clean data set. I got an error message `no; data in memory would be lost`when I followed `mi extract 5`.

   _1_educ035 _2_educ035 _3_educ035 _4_educ035_5_educ035 
    _1_child035 _2_child035 _3_child035 _4_child035 _5_child035

I have these two problems:

1. Is there a simple method to pool the data and get the best set of
   data? Is the last imputed set is the best solution? or average of
   the 5 series?
2. Can you show me simple code in Stata to extract the
   clean data set which are generated in the above format?

Comment: Welcome.Vist [ask].

Comment: The aim of multiple imputation is not to get the best alternative dataset. This is more of a statistical question because what you want to do is suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear to me what you are actually doing. However, if you get something like `data would be lost`, you can try a `clear` option or whatever does the job in your case. Wrap it in `preserve` ... `restore` to make sure you come back to the original data later.

Comment: Thanks all for attempting to help me. Clarification of my problem: My dataset of 213 people have 10 variable with some missing observations. The Stata mi imputation command generated 20 sets of complete data for each individual. I would like to select and export the 15th set out of 20s to analyse in another software as an original complete data set. The R command to select and extract the 15th set is "completeData <- complete(imputed_Data, 15)" . Please advise equivalent Stata code, that save only the 15th set from the completed data for all 10 variables in a computer file, not in memory file.

Comment: I solved the problem by doing trials and errors as follows. 1.  I saved the imputed data in a memory file as `save Mydata`.  2. I extracted desired set (15th set in this example)  by a Stata code `mi extract 15`.  3. I opened data editor and checked for complete data with no missing values. 4. I saved the complete data set in my PC folder by "save as" menu and gave a new name for the file. Note: Statistical experts suggest using all imputed data-sets  to analyze but use of one complete data set makes life easier for repeating analysis and especially exporting into other software. Thanks.